# How to Receive Email Notifications for Alerting State Alerts in Grafana

Tags: smtp, grafana, monitoring, email-notifications, grafana-alerts

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am working on setting up alerting in Grafana and would like to ensure that my team receives email notifications for any alerts that enter the alerting state. Although I have configured basic alerts within Grafana, I am encountering difficulties in setting up the email notifications correctly.

Current Setup:

Alert Configuration: I have set up alerts based on certain metrics crossing predefined thresholds.

Issues Encountered:

Despite the alert being in the alerting state, emails are not being sent out.

Question:

What are the detailed steps to correctly set up email notifications for alerts in the alerting state in Grafana?

I am seeking guidance on how to ensure that email notifications are reliably sent for alerts in the alerting state. Any insights, examples, or common pitfalls to avoid would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!